# Trying to populate an array in mongo shell

Tags: arrays, mongodb

Im trying to populate the array that I describe below results and the output give me the array with 4 null elements

```
  "result" : [
          {
                  "maxTemp" : 83,
                  "group_id" : "Florida"
          },
          {
                  "maxTemp" : 57,
                  "group_id" : "New Mexico"
          },
          {
                  "maxTemp" : 81,
                  "group_id" : "California"
          },
          {
                  "maxTemp" : 57,
                  "group_id" : "Vermont"
          }
  ],
  "ok" : 1
```

the code is

```
db.data.aggregate( 
           {
             $group: {
                 _id: "$State"
               , maxTemp: { $max :"$Temperature"}
             }
           },
           { $project: {
                _id: 0,
                group_id:"$_id",
                maxTemp: "$maxTemp"
            }}
        ).result.forEach(function(match) {
            results.push(db.data.findOne(match));
        });
```

but the output give this result

```
> results
[ null, null, null, null ]
```

what could I do to populate results?

Comment: I remember this question from the mongodb admin course. I would recommend either doing it in the shell entirely, as the question on that course asks, or using the aggregation framework, but not mixing the two. With the aggregation framework, break the question into parts and gradually build it up till you get the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is close to valid so I'll give it a "fair" try. But your problem here is you changed the field names, so unless they are made to be the same you will not get a match. Hence the `null` responses:

```js
var results = [];

db.data.aggregate([
   { "$group": {
       "_id": "$State", 
       "maxTemp": { "$max" :"$Temperature"}
   }},
   { "$project": {
       "_id": 0,
       "State":"$_id",
       "Temperature": "$maxTemp"
   }}
).result.forEach(function(match) {
    results.push(db.data.findOne(match));
});
```